# Fruit bearing plants in shade of northern wall?

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-recommendations, sunlight

Are there any fruit bearing bushes (preferably) or similar fruit bearing plants or small trees which can be grown on northern side of the house which is typically covered by shadow more hours than other places? We are in Central Europe, [hardiness zone 7a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardiness_zone#Central_Europe). The place for plants is more than 10 meters long and 0.6 meters wide (to keep another 0.6 meters for width of path. Of course, in case of small trees, their tops can be wider, up to 2 meters, reaching over the fence.) In our area, prevalent winds blow from the north, directly against this wall.

We are looking to utilize that narrow strip and we want to avoid vegetables or flowers there as this is zone frequently visited by our dog.

Comment: Maybe grape vine can be put on such narrow strip of land.. you could guide it on some trellis/support structure and keep it controll by pruning?

Comment: @FalseIdentity – thanks for the comment, I did not mention grape vine in the possibilities because we already have some elsewhere. Yes, trellis/support can be added.

Comment: @FalseIdentity – maybe you can still add the grape vine as an answer, it has its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best plant I immediately think of would be BLUEBERRIES.  Prolific fruit, some types early, mid season others late season.  Love acidic soil.  Next to your foundation I would test that soil first for pH...a couple of reliable tests to match.  Soil next to the foundation gets lots of lime and raises the pH.  Old foundations, not so much.  10' wide by 30 or 40 feet long in partial shade...in Europe with normally more acidic prone soils?

Plant in a staggered row.  Keep like species together.  Some get 6 X 6' some get only 2'X 2'... get the pH to 5.5.  Use sulfur.  Peat moss doesn't change the pH much if the soil as yours seems to be, buffered with organic matter from centuries?

Blueberries would be fabulous, and beautiful as well!

Comment: And possibly blackberries, if you want to cover more your wall. Blackcurrant could also be ok. Some people say pears, but I'm less sure (I never saw one in shadow).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi or raspberries. That’s what I immediately thought of. 60cm isn’t much...

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to ask additional question (just a quick comment - optional - will be enough) whether article like [this](https://www.gardenersworld.com/plants/10-best-fruit-crops-for-shade/) also offers useful tips for this case or whether it is targeted at different scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Morello cherry is supposed to do OK on a shady wall. In 2014 Monty Don planted one in his garden for the BBC gardening programme "Gardeners' World". Here's a clip: http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p01xl8z5